# How to declare per neuron connections in a pytorch model?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, biological-neural-network

I want to create a brain-alike mess:

- We have input tensor `I` of length `n` and output tensor `O` of length `p`
- In between, we have `K` "intersection" layers
- At intersection layers, neurons share their values at that time with a random subset of "close" neurons (`+-` range `c`). In the form of w_i*current_neuron_val
- and `J` "creation" layers new neurons are created from a set or ReLued  "close" neurons (`+-` range `c`). closed neurons do not go into deeper layers.

Can we do such a thing with PyTorch so that such model will be trainable?

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own class based on nn.Module and make realisation for forward and backward manually. I guess those brain-like-mess connections you have to control through feature labeling inside tensor (aka "0" - no connection).
Because all frameworks use tensors - they by default fully connected and another behavior have to be inducation in the code.

see code of [bindsNET](https://github.com/BindsNET/bindsnet) - how they implement spike-like model using pytorch